# Setting doctype transitional for xhtml file fails

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to generate this line in a html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Since I generate the html file using an xsl file and an xml file, I think the code used to generate the line should be included in the xsl file.

I found this solution on Internet ----

```
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" indent="yes" />
```

but when I change strict to transitional, things go wrong.

Does anyone have a good solution?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "when I change strict to transitional, things go wrong"? Can you add an example of what goes wrong?

Comment: If you go to your doctor and say you don't feel well, he's going to ask for more information about the symptoms. Similarly, if you post on a forum saying "things go wrong", people are going to ask you to explain exactly what happens.

Answer (score 1):

This instruction is absolutely correct from the point of view of compilation:

```
<xsl:output method="html" 
   doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" 
   doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" indent="yes"/>
```

It is not correct from the point of view of the doctype. Because you are going to generate a well-formed XML document based on a specific DTD you should better change your output method to `xml`:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" 
 doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" 
 doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" indent="yes"/>
```

However there is not reason why the first instruction above should not work. Maybe your XSLT processor takes care of the output method.

Comment: hi, empo. Thank you very much. Today I find this piece of code makes everything right. I am not sure why it is. Anyway, it solves my problem. <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" />.

Comment: Oh, the code I post just now is the same as yours. I am quite curious how you get the answer. How did you learn to transform xml to html? Can you please give me some advice, like what books should I read? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your first and second line are not the same. Your desired output is `XHTML` but your found solution, the second line, describes `HTML`.  Because you want XHTML (which is basically HTML with a XML Syntax) use this line like @empo (+1) already described:

```js
<xsl:output method="xml" 
 doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" 
 doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" indent="yes"/>
```

Some XSLT processors also support xhtml as output method (like e.g. Saxon). But this is not a standard (in XSLT 1.0), use XML instead.

XML->XHTML conversion is no big difference compared to XML->XML.

Comment: In XSLT 2.0, xhtml is a standard output method.